# PHP PDO bindParam doesn't modify the query

Tags: mysql, database, pdo, prepared-statement, bindparam

I have the following code:

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
    $sql = "SELECT klantnr, persnr, naam, voornaam FROM gegevens WHERE voornaam LIKE % :voorwaarde % OR naam LIKE % :voorwaarde %";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':voorwaarde', $_GET['q']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':voorwaarde', $_GET['q']);
    echo $stmt->queryString;
    $stmt->execute();
    $pers = $stmt->fetchAll();
    print_r($pers);
}
```

But the query that shows up from the queryString function is still:

```
SELECT klantnr, persnr, naam, voornaam FROM gegevens WHERE voornaam LIKE % :voorwaarde % OR naam LIKE % :voorwaarde %
```

Comment: It is possible to get a rendered query (i.e. with bound variables replaced with their values) by using `PDOStatement::$queryString`—but that is subject to two conditions: (i) you must be using PDO's prepare statement emulation (which is the default, but generally not a great idea); and (ii) you must bind *values*, not *variables*.  As documented under [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php): "Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), **the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.**"

Comment: Just a piece of advice, you don't need to bind the parameter twice if the same parameter name is used multiple times in the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a `LIKE` search with PDO, you must be a little bit witty. What PDO does is that it quotes strings. What does that mean for you? It means that your `% :term %` won't be a valid SQL.

To get the proper SQL out and to correctly clean the input string, use the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT klantnr, persnr, naam, voornaam FROM gegevens WHERE voornaam LIKE CONCAT('%', :voorwaarde, '%') OR naam LIKE CONCAT('%',  :voorwaarde,  '%')";
```

What the above does is concatenating the wildcards for `LIKE` search to your, now clean, search string.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, just a small tip for your future questions - do ask about the real problem, not about what you attempted to do to get down to the core of the problem. Anyway, a lucky guess that your issue was invalid SQL helped, good luck and have fun using PDO! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are working with prepared statements. That means that the query has placeholder wich will replaced by the database. This will not modify your query string.

use `$stmt->debugDumpParams();` to see wich parameter are binded.

Comment: Okay that's clear, i get it. But is there an other way to see which query is executed by the database? And the array $pers at the end is also empty. ($_GET['q'] is filled, i checked with an echo, and there should be at least one result)

Comment: SQL: [117] SELECT klantnr, persnr, naam, voornaam FROM gegevens WHERE voornaam LIKE '%:voorwaarde%' OR naam LIKE '%:voorwaarde%' Params: 1 Key: Name: [11] :voorwaarde paramno=-1 name=[11] ":voorwaarde" is_param=1 param_type=2 Array ( )